# How to use arrays in VBA functions?

Tags: arrays, vba, function

I need to do public function that takes values from certain array and computes  f(x) function for every x, where f(x) = x^3 + 1/5x +2. [this is what I am doing but doesnt work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8yrC.jpg)

Comment: Please post the code in-line, not as an image. Use the edit button to do so.

Comment: Also, what exactly do you mean by "doesn't work"? Error message? Wrong outcome?

Comment: See [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IAzIj.png) for a partial explanation..

Comment: @Jeeped Please post this image as an answer! :)

Comment: lol  jeeped good one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jeeped's comment is a very probable reason of your code malfunctioning, unless you have `Option Base 1` at the top of your code pane. so either you have/place that statement or you change the `ReDim` statements to `ReDim B(1 To nrows, 1 To ncols) As Double`

moreover you must invert  `Next I` and `Next j`

finally I'd suggest you to:

- use `Long` variable type instead of `integer` for `nrows` and `i` variables, should you ever deal with a `datarange` with more than 32767 rows. and assume the same type for `ncols` and `j` for simplicity
- use a "simple" (not array) double variable for `A` since you only need as a temporary "x" value for calculating the corresponding "y" value and store this latter only in B() array, to be eventually returned by your function.

so it could be:

```
Function functionvalue(datarange)

Dim nrows As Long, ncols As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long

Dim A As Double, B() As Double

nrows = datarange.Rows.Count
ncols = datarange.Columns.Count

ReDim B(1 To nrows, 1 To ncols) As Double

For i = 1 To nrows
    For j = 1 To ncols
        A = datarange.Cells(i, j)
        B(i, j) = A ^ 3 + A * 1 / 5 + 2
    Next j
Next i

functionvalue = B

End Function
```